# How to print a list from user input sentence?

Tags: python

So I am supposed to make a script that asks user to make a sentence then discard all characters but lower case and print the lower case letters like this  ['m', 'y', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'].

My script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")

for letter in sentence:
    if letter.islower():
        print(letter)
```

and this is the output:

> ```
> o
> e
> s
> h
> i
> s
> w
> r
> k
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem. - You probably need to accumulate all those characters in a list the print the list - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to produce a list, you have list comprehensions to make life easy:

```
l = ['P', 'm', 'y', 'H', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd']

out = [i for i in l if i.islower()]
print(out)
# ['m', 'y', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```

---

Which is equivalent to:

```
out = []
for i in l:
    if i.islower():
        out.append(i)

print(out)
# ['m', 'y', 'p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `end = ","`:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")

for letter in sentence:
    if letter.islower():
        print(letter, end=",")
#                         ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is almost OK, only instead of *printing* every lowercase character, *append it* to a list, and finally *print only that list*:

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence: ")

lowercases = []                    # prepare an empty list

for letter in sentence:
    if letter.islower():
        lowercases.append(letter)

print(lowercases)                  # print the filled list
```

---

Test:

```
Enter a sentence: The End of Universe.
['h', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'o', 'f', 'n', 'i', 'v', 'e', 'r', 's', 'e']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the method that I actually used.

Comment: It's not letting me. Telling me that I need a reputation higher than 15 to vote.

Comment: Oh, yes. I just helped you a little to reach it. :-)